# Div And Class Element Dont Respond To CSS Customisation

Tags: html, css, blogger

I would like help with a copyright statement that I'm trying to code for the bottom of my blog. I have the basics covered and everything appears as I would like it to apart from two small aspects that I'm having a really difficult time in resolving.

The first issue that I'm having is that the " © 2015 Blankesque . All rights reserved . Terms Of Use " statement that appears on the left side is a little far top than I would like it. I have tried the following piece of css coding to fix the problem but to no avail:

```
.copyright {
top: 10px;
}
```

Ideally I would like the text to be in the middle, in line with the social media icons.

The second issue that I'm facing is with the social icons that are on the right. I would like the icons to be slightly to the left. I have tried the following css coding to resolve the issue but to no avail either:

```
#socialmediabuttons {
padding-right: 3%;
}
```

I have included the entire css and html coding below. The URL to my blog is as follows: http://www.blankesque.com

```
<style>
.copyright {
background: #f8f8f8;
padding: 1% 0 1% 2%;
margin-bottom: -35px;
font-weight: normal!important;
letter-spacing: 0.09em;
overflow: hidden;
font-family: karla, helvetica!important;
font-size: 9px!important;
color: #333333!important;
text-transform: uppercase!important;
}
</style>

<h3 class='copyright'>&#169;  2015 Blankesque . All rights reserved . <a href='http://www.blankesque.com/p/terms-and-conditions.html' style='font-weight:normal!important;'>Terms Of Use</a>

<style>
#socialmediabuttons {
display: block;
text-align: right;
}
#socialmediabuttons a {
padding: 0px 10px;
}
#socialmediabuttons a:hover {
opacity: 0.6;
filter: alpha(opacity=60);
}

</style>
<div id="socialmediabuttons"> 

<a href='https://www.pinterest.com/blankesque' target='_blank'><img alt='Pinterest' height="20px" width="20px" src='http://i1379.photobucket.com/albums/ah140/mynamesiram/Mobile%20Uploads/C633D0E8-96C1-4A46-95F3-900760AD135D_zpsigupftnl.jpg'/>
</a>

<a href='https://www.twitter.com/itsblankesque' target='_blank'><img alt='Twitter' height="20px" width= "20px" src='http://i1379.photobucket.com/albums/ah140/mynamesiram/Mobile%20Uploads/A036F9A7-1B42-42A6-9DF4-29FE498F231D_zpshfhfvks2.jpg'/></a>

<a href='http://www.bloglovin.com/people/aladyinwhite-8315551' target='_blank'><img alt='Bloglovin'  height="20px" width= "20px" src='http://i1379.photobucket.com/albums/ah140/mynamesiram/Mobile%20Uploads/9C819F2F-9B87-4942-BF00-7CB8217E85FE_zpsf0tdks5d.jpg'/></a>

<a href='https://Instagram.com/itsblankesque' target='_blank'><img alt='Instagram' height='20px' width='20px' src='http://i1379.photobucket.com/albums/ah140/mynamesiram/Mobile%20Uploads/0396D9B2-5B1D-47D3-8D95-826663933DA9_zpsw2tay8h2.jpg'/></a>

<a href='mailto: blankesque@hotmail.com' target='_blank'><img alt='Email' height="20px" width= "20px" src='http://i1379.photobucket.com/albums/ah140/mynamesiram/Mobile%20Uploads/45AA973D-D8A1-4FAE-A31A-138DA7CB8443_zpsteklwczz.jpg'/></a>
</div>
</h3><div><br/></div><div><br/></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you change `text-align: right` to `float:right` in the `#socialmediabuttons` styles and set `line-height:20px` on the `.copyright` styles you'll have the effect you desire.